# how to read this relay diagram

Tags: relay

I am a little confused on how this W171Dip-7 relay works.  I know 2 is pos 5v and 6 is neg 5v.     Looks like the signal from 1/14 will go to 8 / 7 when closed.  But i cant tell if 13 is tied to 14 or just over lapping. Same with 9/8/7   or is 2 going straight to 13?

Any help would be great!

[image]

Comment: does the relay have a 10 V coil?

Comment: 5v coil according to datasheet

Comment: 13 is not tied to 14 ... if it was, then 8 would have to be tied to 9 which would render the device completely useless

Comment: `5v coil according to datasheet` ... then 6 is connected to ground (0 V), not to -5 V

Comment: yes correct on 5v.,  so is 13 and 9 just another way to energize the coil?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fccDDM.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Redrawn relay pinout.*

[image]

*Figure 2. Datasheet schematic.*

But i cant tell if 13 is tied to 14 or just overlapping.

The schematic is inconsistent. There is a dot to indicate a connection on 1-14 but it is missing on 7-8. If 1 was connected to 2 then 6 would be connected to 7 and the relay would short circuit the coil when energised.

Answer (score 0):

It's a reed relay in a DIP package. Each connection goes to two pins, because that makes the internal lead frame more robust.

- pins 1 and 14 are one of the reed contacts
- pins 2 and 13 are the positive end of the coil and diode combo
- pins 6 and 9 are the negative end of the coil/diode.
- pins 7 and 8 are the other reed contact

Answer (score 0):

Based on the diagram you provide, every connection on the relay is broken out to two pins.

- Pin 1 is connected to 14
- Pin 2 is connected to 13
- Pin 6 is connected to 9
- Pin 7 is connected to 8

This gives you options on how you actually connect to the relay.  You can energize the relay from pins 2 and 6, or 13 and 9, or a combination of them.

When I search for the W171DIP-7, I find the following datasheet.  Page 10 shows the pinout, and appears that pins 9 and 13 are not connected.  Maybe a different manufacturer?

[W171DIP-7 Datasheet](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/174376.pdf?_ga=2.178322660.1711752795.1571269547-1696913018.1568732862&_gac=1.15346434.1571269547.EAIaIQobChMI56eUl_uh5QIVB6vsCh0tKgPDEAAYASAAEgIJDvD_BwE)